# why does this basic routing situation not work:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

error:

```
No route matches "/en/member/update_profile"
```

edit_profile.html.haml:

```
  =simple_form_for @m, :url => member_update_profile_path do |f|
```

in browser:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/en/member/update_profile" class="simple_form user" id="edit_user_1508" method="post">
```

member_controller_test.rb (succeeds)

```
  post "update_profile"
```

rake routes:

```
  member_update_profile POST   /:locale/member/update_profile(.:format)         {:controller=>"member", :action=>"update_profile"}
```

Comment: Are you doing something tricky to make your controller use the model name (singular) rather than the rails default (plural)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the simple_form_for and rails weren't on the same page, see the "put" below:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/en/member/update_profile" class="simple_form user" id="edit_user_1508" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="AYxvKwu+qH7vjup1h4/TlGBbvg2M10koPdJDNk2xuOw=">
</div>
```

using this fixed it:

```
  =simple_form_for @m, :url => member_update_profile_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |f|
```